# Prevent socket.getaddrinfo 'resolving' non-existent numeric hostnames?

Tags: python, networking

I'm using `socket.getaddrinfo` to check if a hostname is resolvable, catching `socket.gaierror` to  detect a bad hostname.  This works fine, apart from on some systems strings like "12345" are 'resolved' to junk addresses.

What on earth is going on here, and how can I prevent it from happening?

### Strange behaviour on Python 2.6.6 + CentOS 6.2

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec  7 2011, 20:48:22) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> hostname = "12345"
>>> socket.getaddrinfo(hostname, "22", socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.SOL_TCP)
[(2, 1, 6, '', ('0.0.48.57', 22))]
```

### Expected behaviour on Python 2.7.2 + OS X 10.6

```
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> hostname = "12345"
>>> socket.getaddrinfo(hostname, "22", socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.SOL_TCP)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string gets resolved as an ip address. Try `hostname="1"` and you will see it resolving to 0.0.0.1. This is a strange behavior indeed, the manual says that:

`inet_aton() also accepts strings with less than three dots; see the Unix manual page inet(3) for details.`

the man page says that strings like that are `interpreted as a 32-bit value that is stored directly into the binary address without any byte rearrangement.`

Comment: Fun fact: The url http://1076000524/ causes firefox to connect to stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12), though the http server rejects the request.